# SharePoint Online and list based global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, navigation, modern-experience

Is it possible to create a list based navigation in SharePoint Online?

In 2013 we could use code to create it, is it a possibility here?

Everything seems much more limited.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online modern experience, you can use [SPFx extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to create custom navigation - Specifically Application Customizer.

You can find more information & sample codes to get started with at:

1. [SPFx Side Navigation Project for Modern Sites](https://thomasdaly.net/2020/06/09/spfx-side-navigation-project-for-modern-sites/)
2. [Navigation Bar In SPFx With Current User Greetings](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/navigation-bar-in-spfx-with-current-user-greetings2)

---

I will recommend you to check SharePoint out of the box navigation options as well. Using some of the options you can easily create **mega menu** or **cascading menu** navigation.

1. [Plan and implement SharePoint site navigation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/plan-navigation-modern-experience)
2. [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the left navigation for your lists. Just like this [doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca) said.

And in Team site, a newly created list will have a navigation link created by default on the left navigation. Are you handling a communication site? Would you like to say a bit more about your current site and your goal?